# My car speaks occasionally after it starts

Tags: honda, civic, audio

kind of a weird one. Sometimes my 2008 Honda Civic EX quietly speaks words after it starts. I've disconnected any audio devices and it still speaks. As far as I can tell, it's speaking French; I can kinda catch a "s'il vous plaît" at the end of whatever it says. I can't find anything online about this, and it's been driving me up the wall.

Comment: It's not a Bluetooth message, which was n/a until 2009 on the Civic. Does it speak if you fasten your seat belt before starting the engine?

Comment: No, but it also doesn't consistently speak when I don't fasten til after

Comment: So if you always remember to fasten your seat belt before starting, you will never hear the voice again? That sounds like a way to stop being driven up the wall. Confirmed? If so I'll write that in an answer.

Comment: Well no, I haven't fastened my seatbelt enough times before starting the engine to know whether it stops it from speaking.

Comment: I think the only way to know for sure, is if you recorded some audio while starting, and turned off the radio/fan/AC to avoid any extra noises

Answer (score 0):

In comments you've said that the car didn't speak when you fastened your seatbelt before starting the engine, so I'm assuming that this is a "please fasten seatbelt" message.

You also said that you haven't tried this enough times to know if this always works.

So I suggest that you always fasten your seatbelt before starting the engine if you don't want to hear the message. And if it turns out that the car still talks, come back and post a new question.